# Missing data in lambda when using mokito's spy

Tags: kotlin, testing, mockito, mockito-kotlin

I'm testing my code with mokito-kotlin and I run into a situation where a executed lambda has wrong data. I found out that the "scope" as I know it from JavaScript is different then expected. The `this` of the lambda is a different one when I use `spy()`.

Here is my simplified test:

```
@Test
fun strangeLambda() {
    open class Foo {
        var bar: String? = null
        val lambda = { bar }
        fun magic() = lambda()
    }

    Foo().apply {
        bar = "jo"
        assertEquals(magic(), "jo")
    }
    spy(Foo()).apply {
        bar = "no"
        assertEquals(bar, "no") // passes as expected
        assertEquals(magic(), "no") // fails: magic returns null!
    }
}
```

What is going on here and how can I fix it? I'm spying the object because I want to verify that some methods are called, but that does not matter here.

Comment: Mh... I found in the javadoc this _"Sets the instance that will be spied. Actually copies the internal fields of the passed instance to the mock."_ So lambda still points to the original object which is not updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution is now to subclass the class I'm interested in and making the constructor internal so that just I can use it. In the subclass I check if I get the params I expect.